# Elasticsearch script parameter containsAll with value from document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use an elasticsearch script query using the Java SDK to determine if a collection of IDs passed as a parameter contains all of the values in the indexed document.

Here is a simple example, that *does not* work, i'm expecting this to match the a document, but it doesn't.

The document `attributes` field is an array with a single item `[2]`

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = boolQuery();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "list", Arrays.asList( 1L, 2L, 3L ) );

String expr = "params.list.containsAll(doc['attributes'])";

Script script = new Script( ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", expr, Collections.emptyMap(), params );

qb.should( scriptQuery( script ) );
```

However, i've tried these various hard coded alternatives that do work

Hard coded `.contains(2)` works as expected

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = boolQuery();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "list", Arrays.asList( 2L ) );

String expr = "params.list.contains(2)";

Script script = new Script( ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", expr, Collections.emptyMap(), params );

qb.should( scriptQuery( script ) );
```

Hard coded `.containsAll([2])` works as expected

```
BoolQueryBuilder qb = boolQuery();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "list", Arrays.asList( 2L ) );

String expr = "params.list.containsAll([2])";

Script script = new Script( ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", expr, Collections.emptyMap(), params );

qb.should( scriptQuery( script ) );
```

Comment: `doc['attributes'].value`

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris actually tried that too but didn't post the example, that just gets the first value, and causes a `class_cast_exception: Cannot cast java.lang.Long to java.util.Collection` because the first value is a Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta cast the `params.list` elements before calling `containsAll`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": """
              params.list.stream()
                         .map(num -> (long) num)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList())
                         .containsAll(
                           doc['attributes'].stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))""",
              "params": {
                "list": [
                  2
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

assuming your mapping truly defined the `atributes` as such:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```